# React-Native Build Succeeded - Native module cannot be null (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

I am running a native-react app on my local El Capitan Mac OS X machine.  I am trying to get it to run in simulator for iOS.

The build is succeeding but I am seeing a red screen with the words: Native module cannot be null.

I am seeing this error in console:

```
NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file global code@http://localhost:8081/index.ios.js in any of the roots: ["/Users/User/f8app"]
    at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (/Users/User/f8app/node_modules/node-haste/lib/index.js:288:13)
    at /Users/User/f8app/node_modules/node-haste/lib/index.js:226:30
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:401:9)
```

How do I fix this?  Thank you.

React-native version:
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.28.0

EDIT: This is incredibly confusing, because index.ios.js is in the root of my project.

Comment: It may not be relevant but since RN0.29 there is no more struggle with appDelegate (automatic guess). Try to upgrade if you don't have answers it won't hurt to be in a latest release.

Comment: for some reason, my react won't update past 28, even if I type "react-native upgrade"

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and it took a while to narrow down the cause issue. React sometimes does not does  automatically link sublibraries to iOS project. Your library might require some of the additional `RCT*` dependencies, which are downloaded and are in node_modules/react-native folder. You will need to link it manually.

For example I used CocoaPods for iOS dependency management and my react native looks like this:

```
pod 'React', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
   'Core',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket'
  ]
```

If you are using `react-native link` or manually linking in `XCode`, make sure to add these files into your Xcode project. More details in [Facebook documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node modules, podfile.lock and pods folder inside ios folder.
2. Run yarn install in project directory.
3. Run pod install inside ios folder.